# core bluetooth state restoration only fires once

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying to get core bluetooth state restoration working consistently in swift, but i can only seem to get it to fire once, and then it doesnt respond anymore...

so far i have in my class init:

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    let centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: centralQueue, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "myCentralManager", CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true]) 

}
```

and my WillRestoreState delegate:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : AnyObject]) {       

    let peripheral = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] 

    for peripheral in peripherals as! [CBPeripheral] {
        showGenericNotification("BLE \(peripheral)")
        peripheral.delegate = bleService
    }   
}
```

then when i send data from the BLE device the showNotification() puts a notification in my Notification Center.. and it only fires once, then stops responding.  bleService is the instance with CBPeripheralDelegate that manages the peripheral

doesnt seem like the delegate is assigning to the bleService... anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CBCentralManager` has a method `scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)` where you specify options for scanning. By default, this manager generates one discovery event for multiple peripheral packets received, as stated in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerscanoptionallowduplicateskey). You have to pass `true` value under the `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` for options dictionary to get expected effect:

> filtering is disabled and a discovery event is generated each time the central receives an advertising packet from the peripheral

Then, delegate method for state restoration will be called more than once, but only if it has to be called, i.e. if between discovery events service was disabled.